# Complex Dynamics book Recommendation

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, complex-dynamics

I know the basics of Complex Analysis and Topology and I would like to learn Complex Dynamics. One book I found was Beardon's *Iteration of
Rational Functions*. I'm not sure whether its a good book for beginners.

Any recommendation on books on Complex Dynamics for beginners?

Comment: See http://math.bu.edu/people/bob/books.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Milnor's book "Dynamics in one complex variable" is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Beardon's book is absolutely perfect for beginners. This book basically gives ideas of dynamics of rational functions. Milnor's book is also fine but it is slight different than Beardon's book.

For the dynamics of meromorphic functions, one can follow "Iteration of meromorphic functions" by Walter Bergweiler.

Along with this one can find some literature of Zhang Guan-Hou (Chapter 4 of "Theory of Entire and Meromorphic Functions: Deficient and Asymptotic Values and Singular Directions")  which is very important to study complex dynamics.